# What does [CFWS] and [FWS] mean in this ABNF?

Tags: validation, email, abnf

The [RFC 2282](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.2.5) for emails have the below ABNF for quoted-string.

```
quoted-string   =       [CFWS]
                        DQUOTE *([FWS] qcontent) [FWS] DQUOTE
                        [CFWS]
```

I googled and foundthat CFWS is Comments, Folding, Whitespaces. I know what whitespaces are but don't what comments and folding is in terms of ABNF in an email address.

Also what does [FWS] inside *() mean? The double quotes can have 0 or more occurences of qcontent preceded by Folding and whitespaces?

This is very confusing. References to understand ABNF would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that RFC 2282 was obsoleted in 2008 by [RFC 5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322).

Answer (score 12):

This isn't part of the generic ABNF syntax (currently defined in [RFC 5234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234), although [RFC 2234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2234) was the definition of ABNF in play at the time that RFC 2282 was written). Rather, `FWS` and `CFWS` are special tokens defined in the email RFC itself (see [section 3.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.2.3) of RFC 2822, or [section 3.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) of RFC 5322, which obsoleted RFC 2822 in 2008).

From RFC 5322:

> #### [2.2.3.  Long Header Fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2.3)
>
> Each header field is logically a single line of characters
> comprising  the field name, the colon, and the field body.  For
> convenience  however, and to deal with the 998/78 character
> limitations per line,  the field body portion of a header field can be
> split into a  multiple-line representation; this is called "folding".
> The general  rule is that wherever this specification allows for
> folding white  space (not simply WSP characters), a CRLF may be
> inserted before any  WSP.
>
> For example, the header field:
>
> ```
> Subject: This is a test
> ```
>
> can be represented as:
>
> ```
> Subject: This
>  is a test
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The process of moving from this folded multiple-line representation
> of a header field to its single line representation is called
> "unfolding".  Unfolding is accomplished by simply removing any CRLF
> that is immediately followed by WSP.  Each header field should be
> treated in its unfolded form for further syntactic and semantic
> evaluation.  An unfolded header field has no length restriction and
> therefore may be indeterminately long.
>
> ...
>
> #### [3.2.2.  Folding White Space and Comments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.2)
>
> White space characters, including white space used in folding
> (described in [section 2.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2.3)), may appear between many elements in
> header field bodies.  Also, strings of characters that are treated as
> comments may be included in structured field bodies as characters
> enclosed in parentheses.  The following defines the folding white
> space (FWS) and comment constructs.
>
> Strings of characters enclosed in parentheses are considered
> comments    so long as they do not appear within a "quoted-string", as
> defined in    [section
> 3.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.4).  Comments may nest.
>
> There are several places in this specification where comments and
> FWS    may be freely inserted.  To accommodate that syntax, an
> additional    token for "CFWS" is defined for places where comments
> and/or FWS can    occur.  However, where CFWS occurs in this
> specification, it MUST NOT    be inserted in such a way that any line
> of a folded header field is    made up entirely of WSP characters and
> nothing else.
>
> ```
> FWS             =   ([*WSP CRLF] 1*WSP) /  obs-FWS
>                                        ; Folding white space
>
> ctext           =   %d33-39 /          ; Printable US-ASCII
>                     %d42-91 /          ;  characters not including
>                     %d93-126 /         ;  "(", ")", or "\"
>                     obs-ctext
>
> ccontent        =   ctext / quoted-pair / comment
>
> comment         =   "(" *([FWS] ccontent) [FWS] ")"
>
> CFWS            =   (1*([FWS] comment) [FWS]) / FWS
> ```
>
> Throughout this specification, where FWS (the folding white space
> token) appears, it indicates a place where folding, as discussed in
> [section 2.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2.3), may take place.  Wherever folding appears in a
> message (that is, a header field body containing a CRLF followed by
> any WSP), unfolding (removal of the CRLF) is performed before any
> further semantic analysis is performed on that header field according
> to this specification. That is to say, any CRLF that appears in FWS is
> semantically "invisible".
>
> A comment is normally used in a structured field body to provide some
> human-readable informational text.  Since a comment is allowed to
> contain FWS, folding is permitted within the comment.  Also note that
> since quoted-pair is allowed in a comment, the parentheses and
> backslash characters may appear in a comment, so long as they appear
> as a quoted-pair.  Semantically, the enclosing parentheses are not
> part of the comment; the comment is what is contained between the two
> parentheses.  As stated earlier, the "" in any quoted-pair and the
> CRLF in any FWS that appears within the comment are semantically
> "invisible" and therefore not part of the comment either.
>
> Runs of FWS, comment, or CFWS that occur between lexical tokens in a
> structured header field are semantically interpreted as a single space
> character.

Comment: What does that mean for an average Joe writing code to make use of HTTP headers? From what I've gathered parenthesized comments can also be almost anywhere in an HTTP header.

Comment: @PHPGuru Not HTTP headers - the quote here is about *email* headers.